# Specifying CSS stack order without using z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I am wondering if either of the following are possible:

1. Is there a way to use z-index without specifying the position attribute for an element.
2. Is there any way to specify the CSS stack order for elements without using either the z-index property or the position attribute

Comment: I think the answer is no and no (except for the possibility @amosrivera shows). What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) `z-index` can only work on positioned elements.
2. The only other way is change the order of the elements in the html.

Comment: Jejeje yes, i'm following Paul Irish on twitter, saw it a while ago. Although w3schools might not be the best resource for JS documentation, i think it is a decent one for basic things such as CSS. What do you think?

Comment: It's not as bad for CSS as it is for JS and HTML.  It's still bad. http://w3fools.com/#csssucks

Answer (score 0):

(1) No. [see the CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

> For a positioned box, the 'z-index'
>   property specifies:
>      1. The stack level ...
>
> Each *positioned* box in a given
>   stacking context has an integer stack
>   level.

(2) No. the CSS stack order *is* the z-index